# All ts files are not recording in the same m3u8 file

Tags: nginx, http-live-streaming, rtmp, m3u8

I am trying to use nginx-rtmp for HLS and using the m3u8 file for VOD as well. But after few time the #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE is set to some other value while I want to record all the ts files in that m3u8 file.
m3u8 file :-

**

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:34
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
#EXTINF:5.367,
awsfloor-34.ts
#EXTINF:8.333,
awsfloor-35.ts
#EXTINF:8.333,
awsfloor-36.ts
#EXTINF:8.334,
awsfloor-37.ts
#EXTINF:8.333,
awsfloor-38.ts
#EXTINF:8.333,
awsfloor-39.ts
#EXTINF:8.334,
awsfloor-40.ts
#EXTINF:8.333,
awsfloor-41.ts
#EXTINF:8.333,
awsfloor-42.ts
#EXTINF:8.334,
awsfloor-43.ts
#EXTINF:1.927,
awsfloor-44.ts**
```

**

my rtmp block:-
**

```
application thirdhlslive {  #rtmp push stream request path
            live on;
            hls on;
            hls_path /usr/share/nginx/html/thirdhlslive;
            hls_cleanup off;
            hls_fragment 3s;
            hls_playlist_length 1m;
        #record all;
        #record_path /tmp/recordings;
        #record_suffix _recorded.mp4;
        #record_unique on;
        #record_max_size 1024K;     
        }
```

**

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

So what's happening for you is that old segments roll out at the top of the playlist (i.e. it's a sliding live window) but you want them to stay.

Using the `hls_type` directive (more info [here](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives#hls_type)) you can change the playlist type from a sliding window to a growing window type stream which in HLS is called `EVENT` type. Additionally, you might also have to increase the `hls_playlist_length` value so that is larger than the duration of the recording you cant to make.

So you would change to:

```
  live on;
  hls on;
  hls_path /usr/share/nginx/html/thirdhlslive;
  hls_cleanup off;
  hls_fragment 3s;
  hls_playlist_length 10h;
  hls_type event;
```